# lsmod returns nothing on my embedded device

Tags: drivers, embedded, kernel-modules

I have put a vendor supplied embedded Linux installation [(called X-Linux)](http://www.dmp.com.tw/tech/os-xlinux/) onto a hardware device. I ran `lsmod` to see what modules are loaded and nothing at all is shown. Also there is no /proc/modules directory on the system. What does this mean? Does it mean that no drivers are loaded to communicate with the rest of the devices on the board (ethernet, serial etc?). I don't see how this can be as I have been able to configure the static IP of the board and am able to successfull `ftpget` files from my desktop development machine. I really am unsure about what is going on and about the stability of the system. Is this is a problem or is it expected behaviour?

Comment: `/proc/modules` is a file rather than a directory

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This just means that the drivers are compiled directly into the kernel and that the kernel does not have module support. If you know exactly your target system and the purpose you don't necessarily need module support.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. No module support? Does that mean that I will be unable to install any other drivers on the system? I need to install *.ko drivers to support CANBUS-  will I be unable to do so?

Comment: @mathematician1975 if there is no `/proc/modules` file than module support is probably missing, so yes you won't be able to load additional modules. As there are already CAN drivers in the kernel it may already work out of the box. Otherwise you'd have to recompile the kernel.

Comment: Unfortunately that is way beyond my ability at present. Many thanks for your answer anyway.